# I need quick clarification on drupal REST services

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-services

I have written many services resources on the DRUPAL, "n" number of API hit comes to the DRUPAL CMS and access the data in the DRUPAL database.

My question is, when I hit service, Is DRUPAL CMS calling the bootstrap and verify every modules is loaded or not ?

Because I am wondering, there are nearly 100 web services, no more DRUPAL UI is consumed in this project.

So web service will eat site performance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each request to one of your services will bootstrap Drupal in order to be able to reliably uses its APIs. And yes, this is a performances hit since bootstrapping Drupal is not lightweight.

In addition, depending on  how the services are build, they may not provide any kind of caching, unlike traditional pages. Also a Web Services driven page will probably require more than one request, increasing the load on the server.

So yes, Web Services may eat your site performances.

Comment: my observation on drupal, when ever bootstrap is called, drupal system will check, what are the modules are checked and it is loaded or not ? so on every web service request, the system perform this operation. please confirm

Comment: Yes, boostraping Drupal include loading the .module file for all enabled module.